# How to convert a string foo[bar] to an actual array?

Tags: php

I've got an array like this

```
[ 
 "foo[a]" => 1
 "foo[b]" => 2
];
```

and I want to convert it to this:

```
[
"foo"=> ["a"=>1, "b"=>2 ] 
]
```

What I'm trying to do is to fix or repair the value of select elements which livewire sends as described above instead of actual arrays.

I'm sending the value of `Object.fromEntries(new FormData($event.target))` which contain nested data (multiple selects with same name) [as stated here.](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/313#issuecomment-538401606)

Comment: if you use name="foo[]" for every input field in HTML then you will get foo[1], foo[2]...etc

Answer (score 0):

This function will do this for you:

```
 function parseFormData($formData) {
    $data = [];
    foreach ($formData as $key => $value) {
        $openBracket = strpos($key, '[');
        $closeBracket = strpos($key, ']');
        if ($openBracket && $closeBracket) {
            $keyName = substr($key, 0, $openBracket);
            if ($closeBracket - $openBracket != 1) {
                $innerKeyName = substr($key, $openBracket + 1, $closeBracket - $openBracket - 1);    
                $data[$keyName][$innerKeyName] = $value;
            } else {
                $data[$keyName][] = $value;
            }
        } else {
            $data[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

https://paiza.io/projects/UAYoY11fGZhDUv3c8QxOLw